# synchronization, lock passing with broadcast

Tags: algorithm, synchronization, operating-system

I learned about synchronization in class recently, and I'm a little confused about the difference between signal and broadcast. I know for signal, when it happens it wakes up the first thread in its waitlist. That thread will claim the lock after the signal thread unlocks. Then what happens to broadcast? when broadcast is called all the waiting threads are woken up. Then when the broadcast thread unlocks, which of these threads get to take that lock?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the threads are unblocked. All of them try to acquire the lock. Whichever one succeeds first returns from its `wait` function holding the lock. When that thread later releases the lock, one of the threads still trying to acquire it, will get it.

In practice I suspect that on a broadcast the OS will move the waitlist directly across and add it to the list of threads waiting to acquire the lock (accounting for priority if it orders such lists by priority). But that's an implementation detail.

Comment: Query: For a signal OS unblocks a thread which is waiting on a `cond`. What if that thread doesn't lock `mutex`. Does OS unblocks another thread which was also waiting in queue?

Comment: @DoSparKot: unless I misunderstand you, the situation you describe cannot arise unless the thread is asynchronously killed. All of the functions for waiting on a condition variable exit with the mutex held, so there's no way a thread can do anything without taking the mutex first. If the thread is unblocked and then killed, the OS will not wake another thread in its place. The signal to the condition variable will in effect be lost. This is one of several reasons why killing threads can result in code that's difficult to get right.